# How can i enable and disable a user in an Azure sql database from SSMS?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a user on an azure db . I have connected to the azure db from ssms. I anm trying to disable the user and if required enable them. But there doesnt seem to be a "Properties" option when i right click on the user.

How can i do this ?

Comment: SSMS's pop-up dialogs that are used with on-prem SQL for some reason aren't used when connected to Azure SQL (which is silly, _I know_), but in the meantime just run T-SQL directly: i.e. `ALTER LOGIN [loginName] WITH ENABLE/DISABLE;` - note that login-name is not the user-name.

Comment: i dont full get what you are saying .. if i have a user lets say "testUser" in the database what do i run to disable and what do i run to enab;e . Or do i denable/disable from the master database ?

Comment: so i do the following ALTER LOGIN testUser DISABLE and to reenable ALTER LOGIN techonthenet ENABLE. But if this user is in multiple dbs on the server do i ned to do it on the server level from master ?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a `LOGIN` object and a `USER` object: a `USER` object belongs to a database, and a `LOGIN` belongs to the containing server - each `LOGIN` is associated with (at most) 1 `USER` per database. When you disable a `LOGIN` then that person cannot accesss the server (or its databases) at all - but disabling a `USER` (without disabling the `LOGIN`) only disables that person's access to that single database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i enable and disable a user in an Azure sql database from SSMS?

When you disable/enable Logins of a server it will get affected for all the users that are associated with it as @Dai explained in comments.

```sql
ALTER LOGIN loginname DISABLE/ENABLE
```

When you want to enable or disable particular user from database you can grant and revoke the connect permission to it, as it can't connect to database it will not be able to perform any action on database such as:

- To disable users of a database:

```sql
REVOKE CONNECT FROM "username"
```

- To enable users of a database:

```sql
GRANT CONNECT TO "username"
```